# How was the term speed treated in the 16th and 17th centuries?

Tags: physics, terminology, classical-mechanics, 16th-century, 17th-century

What did people in the 16th and 17th centuries mean by the term *speed*? Did they have

$$\text{speed} = \frac{ \text{distance} }{ \text{time} }$$

back then? Or did they have some other notion of speed and this relation came into being somewhat later ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and by whom was the earliest definition of speed given?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2244/when-and-by-whom-was-the-earliest-definition-of-speed-given)

Comment: See the post : [Galileo's Discussion of Uniform Motion](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/galileos-discussion-of-uniform-motion) : Galileo defines *uniform speed* in *Two new sciences*, Third Day, as follows : "By steady or uniform motion, I mean one in which the distances traversed by the moving particle during any equal intervals of time, are themselves equal."